# Scroll list view when click on last showing Edit Text of list Item

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

i am user edit text in a list Item inside of Bottom Tab

I want to scroll listview when user click on last showing edit text Item

i have used

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

in my listview activity but did not work

Here my listview adapter class

```
class CreateAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>  {
String[] strItecode=null;
String[] strItem;
String[] strQuantity;
Context context;

int temp;
CreateAdapter(Context context, String[] strItemcode, String[] strItem,
        String[] strQauntity) {
    super(context, R.layout.create_list_item, R.id.txtItemcode, strItemcode);
    this.context = context;
    this.strItecode = strItemcode;
    this.strItem = strItem;
    this.strQuantity = strQauntity;
   // text= new String[strItem.length];
}
private int editingPosition = 0;
private TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
          public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
              text[editingPosition] = s.toString();
          }
          public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
          public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
      };

public View getView( final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    temp=position;
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater
                .inflate(R.layout.create_list_item, parent, false);

        holder.txtItecode = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtItemcode);
        holder.txtItem = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
        holder.editQuantity = (EditText) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.editcreateQuantity);
        holder.editQuantity.setTag(position);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.editQuantity.removeTextChangedListener(watcher);
   if(text[temp].contentEquals("0"))
       holder.editQuantity.setText("");
   else
    holder.editQuantity.setText(text[temp]);

    holder.editQuantity.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {       
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
          if(hasFocus) editingPosition = position;
        }
    });

    holder.editQuantity.addTextChangedListener(watcher);

    // The rest is good, just make sure to remove the call to setting the EditText's text at the end
    holder.txtItecode.setText(strItecode[position]);
    holder.txtItem.setText(strItem[position]);
  //  holder.editQuantity.setText(text[temp]);

    return convertView;


}


class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtItecode;
    TextView txtItem;
    EditText editQuantity;
}
```

here my list view

```
  <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/listlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_below="@+id/header"
          android:layout_above="@+id/lastbutton">

        <ListView

            android:id="@+id/createlist"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:divider="#eeeeee"
            android:dividerHeight="1dip"
            android:scrollingCache="true"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true"

           android:transcriptMode="normal"
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" >

        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Please suggest me How i can set auto scroll when click on last edit text of list view

Thanks In Advance

Comment: "doesn't work" is not enough information for people to help you... Please add a stacktrace.

Comment: @2Dee Thanks for replay , i am not getting any error , i want to set auto scroll when click on last edit text of list view item but i don't have any idea how can do this

Comment: are you trying to implement lazy loading..?? i.e. when user scrolls up to last item then more data will be fetched from server, database or whatever... is that what you want?

Comment: @Rupesh i am trying to scroll listview when click on last listview item(Edit Text)

Comment: @2Dee Please suggest me a proper way to scroll listview

Comment: @user3886688 scroll to where?? what do you mean by `auto scroll`?? can you please elaborate what r u trying to achieve.. so that we can help you. meanwhile please check the `ListView`'s API http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition%28int%29

Comment: and please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

`EditText` is very difficult to use as a item of a `ListView`. I suggest you to use a `Button`. By clicking on this button open an `AlertDialog` and use `EditText` in side it, enter quantity value press ok and save that value. For example in your adapter class you can write your code like below generic example.

```
btnQuantity.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

                showAlertDialog();

}

});

private void showAlertDialog() 
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        EditText inputQuantity = new EditText(context);

        builder.setTitle("Enter Quantity");

        builder.setView(inputQuantity);

        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                // do your stuff or save entered quantity into any variable or whatever you want to do

            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: there is any way to Scroll listview on btnQuantity.setOnClickListener below method

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you want to add a `ScrollView` when clicked on the last `EditText`.You can try the following code inside `onClickListener` of your Last `EditText` to generate a `ScrollView`.

```
    LinearLayout linLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Your_LinearLayout);

    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    sv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    ll.setOrientation(1);
    sv.addView(ll); // adding a new LinearLayout inside your ScrollView

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
    {
        Button b = new Button(this); //instead of Button you can add anything you want to add inside the LinearLayout of the ScrollView
        b.setText("Button "+i);
        ll.addView(b); //adding the Button to the LinearLayout inside ScrollView
    }

    linLayout.addView(sv);//finally adding the ScrollView to the parent LinearLayout of the layout which you have posted in the question
```

Now if you want to set the entire layout dynamically, then remove below lines in program :

```
LinearLayout linLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Your_LinearLayout);
linLayout.addView(sv);
```

And Add below line :

```
YouActivity.this.setContentView(sv);
```

Hope this helps.

[Follow this tutorial for more info of how to add a ScrollView programmatically](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/130521-android-part-iii-dynamic-layouts/)

Comment: added this code on Getview because edit text is the part of listview item?

Comment: i don't want to add new view , i just want to scroll listview when click last list view Item

Comment: If you want to scroll `ListView` without adding a `ScorollView` then [follow this tutorial](http://benjii.me/2010/08/endless-scrolling-listview-in-android/)

Comment: i want to set auto scroll when user click on last listview item(Edit Text)

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little late, but this answer might help other search for how to do this.
Android's Listview comes with some built-in features for this.  Try

```
 getListView().addFooterView(LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.footer, null));
```

My footer is nothing more than an empty view of the height needed

### footer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            style="@style/bottomCellLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="12dp">

<View
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        style="@style/cellSeparatorLight"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/grayNormal"
        android:layout_height="1dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```